# How to fix animation glitches in Flutter Lottie

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

I have an app with lots of Lottie animations. They work fine in a Windows UWP app and [AirBnB sample Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbnb.lottie). Also look fine in lottiefiles.com online test tool.

But they are glitchy in Flutter using [Lottie for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) package. Not all of them, but many, maybe around a third.

Full source code below, you can try for yourself.

Glitches are either frame overlaps or blinking, as if there is a gap between frames.

Glitches are consistent, i.e. always happen in the same place, so does not seem like a performance issue.
Also, they are not happening between repeats, but in the middle of the animation, so again not an application issue but seems to be the issue with how they are rendered.

I have tried loading them as `composition` from memory with a `controller`. I have also tried a vanilla asset load to rule out issues with my implementation, and they are behaving the same. The issue appears both in the emulator and the actual phone. So it seems to me it is not caused by the way I implemented but by the Lottie package itself, or perhaps an issue with Lottie JSON that for some reason only affects Android.

Full example is below. Just paste this into main.dart and add dependency to yaml: `lottie: ^1.2.1`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Lottie Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Lottie.network(
                  'https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_uz92k22x.json'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is it because your lottie is too complex?

Comment: it's a very simple animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `frameRate: FrameRate.max` like stated below.

```
       Expanded(
          child: Lottie.network('https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_uz92k22x.json', 
              frameRate: FrameRate.max,
              ),
        ),
```

this will render the Lottie animation with the same frame rate of that of the app. In Lottie plugin it will render the json as per the frame rate mentioned in the json file. An animation encoded with a 25 FPS will only be painted 25 times per seconds even though the AnimationController will invalidate the widget 60 times per seconds. Hence this `framerate` was introduced from Lottie 0.6.0

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but it does not help. Changing your code to point to my animation and using a repeat instead of forward you can see the glitches. Using local asset instead of a network location makes no difference
```
Lottie.network(
                  'https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_uz92k22x.json',
              controller: _controller,
              onLoaded: (composition) {
                _controller
                  ..duration = composition.duration
                  ..repeat();
              },
```

Comment: Try adding `frameRate : feamerate.max`. This should force Lottie to paint the animation according to your device's frame rate instead of 25 specified in the json

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I was changing the framerate in AE, and reducing it to 15 or 12 fixes the issue. But I don't understand why

Comment: FrameRate.max works! If you can make that you answer with explanation why it works I'll accept it with bounty! Thanks!

Comment: Can you just make it a complete answer for others to be able to see where frameRate fits

Answer (score 1):

According to the official package [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie)
For Flutter Web, run the app with: `flutter run --web-renderer canvaskit`

Works fine for me in the latest version: lottie: ^1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I use Lottie for Flutter on my applications and it works well also on emulator or on low-performance phones. The problem can be related to bad converted animations, or you can try to use Lottie.asset(yourjson) to avoid potential network fetch issues.

Comment: Animation works fine in Lottie preview app on Android and the web. There seems to be a problem with the Flutter package. Changing frame rate fron 25 to 15 or 12 seems to fix the issue. But it's a lot of work.  We need the package to be fixed